# Import plist animation in Unity or extract frames

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, sprite, plist, sprite-sheet

I've searched a lot on the Google but I don't find the answer that I need.
I've a lot of animation files created for IOS that come with a sprite sheet and relative plist file.
I need to import the frame of these animations in Unity but I don't know how I can do that because there isn't a direct compatibility with plist and I haven't found software that extract the correct frames from sprite sheet. Does anyone know how I can do that?

Comment: .plist files are just XML. Worst case scenario, you could probably parse them yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know that plist is XML but I don't search for the worst scenario ;-) I hope that someone else has just encounter this problem and solve it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`System.XML.XMLDocument`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) (with [**`TextAsset.text`**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextAsset-text.html)) to parse `.plist`, and [**`TextureImporter.spritesheet`**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureImporter-spritesheet.html) with [**`SpriteMetaData`**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteMetaData.html) to read / write spritesheet data.

I'm using XMLDocument in production (it is fast) to read SVG files. For TextureImporter, [here](https://github.com/eppz/Unity.Library.eppz/blob/master/EditorUtils/SliceRenamer.cs) you can see an example where I nudge spritesheets directly with it.

Comment: Thanks Geri for your reply. I don't want using these animations directly from plist, I want import them in Unity and, after that, I want recreate these all animations in Unity. If I understand well you suggested me to run directly these animation in Unity, but is not my goal ;-)

Comment: @LucaPanteghini I used this to rename slices in my project. Similarly, you can write an Editor script that imports the animation data.

Comment: @LucaPanteghini I'm afraid you won't find something "Import my sprite sheet info from plist to Unity" tool out there.

Comment: No, for now I'm waiting a little bit but I'm thinking to write a script that extract from spritesheet the single sprite and, after that, recreate all the animations in Unity. The plist and spritesheet that I'm working on are a little bit complex because them use offset and rotation.

Comment: @LucaPanteghini You can't adjust rotation in a Unity sprite slice. It all sounds beside the importer you'll need even a custom sprite sheet class. :)

Comment: Yes, I need to create an importer that handle the rotation of the sprite and the offset too...

Comment: @LucaPanteghini  I actually don't really get it. What information do you have in those plists exactly? Isn't it sprite animation simply? It does not sound as a sprite slice information (to construct sprite sheet from).

Comment: This is an example of plist that I have: 
    <key>frame</key>
    <string>{{820,176},{144,166}}</string>
    <key>offset</key>
    <string>{-1,-77}</string>
    <key>rotated</key>
    <true/>
    <key>sourceColorRect</key>
    <string>{{67,154},{144,166}}</string>
    <key>sourceSize</key>
    <string>{280,320}</string>

Comment: Anyway, any progress on implmentation? Did you parse it as XML? You can have a start from there...

Comment: In this time I can't work on it because I must finish urgent another project but asap I come back to this issue and try to implement my solution. Thanks for all!